# Failed to post a url query to REST web service - issue with my url?

Tags: php, rest

I am submitting a URL request to a RESTful webservice. When I submit a variable in the url e.g "NGF and trkA", I am able to retrieve an XML responses from the remote server.  However, when I input "NGF/trkA", my request fails. I really do not understand why as I have used rawurlendcode(). See the code below:

```
  <?php

/*After pdf parsing, the result is contained in $fullText.*/
$fullText="NGF/TrkA*";

/*Remove line breaks.*/
$fullText_clean = str_replace("\n", " ", $fullText);


/*Excise the first 2 sentences of $fullText_clean (or 100 characters).*/
$truncated = substr($fullText_clean,0);

// Properly encode $truncated.
$truncated_encode = rawurlencode($truncated);

// Plug this variable, $truncated_encode, into the search url.
$xml = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search/query='.$truncated_encode.'&resulttype=core';


// Return SimpleXMLElement object
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($xml);

if($xmlObject){
//Return information within the desired tag(s).
$title = $xmlObject->resultList->result[0]->title;


echo $fullText."<br />".
 $fullText_clean."<br />".
 $truncated."<br />".
 $truncated_encode."<br />".
 $title;

 /*echo $title."<br />".$truncated;*/

 }else{

echo "Failed to retreive SimpleXMLElement object.";

}

?>
```

This is the error that I get when $fullText="NGF/trkA":

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity   "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search/query=NGF%2FTrkA%2A&result    type=core" in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Lifescieco_pdfUpload/puttingitTogether.php   on line 21
Failed to retreive SimpleXMLElement object.
```

Comment: Try changing the url to `'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query='.$truncated_encode.'&resulttype=core';` Added question mark after `search`

Comment: So it's got nothing to do with the "/" that i use in the submission you think? I thought that might be a problem..

Comment: It seems like it works WITHOUT the rawurlencode() (I tried your actual URL). In the PHP docs it says "Since PHP 5.1.0 you don't need to do this because PHP will do it for you." in reference to urlencoding.